# Filter posts by multiple tags to return posts that have all those tags, with good performance

Tags: mysql, couchdb, nosql, tagging, join

StackOverflow lets you search for posts by tags, and lets you filter by an intersection of tags, e.g. `ruby x mysql x tags`. But typically it's inefficient to retrieve such lists from MySQL using mulitple joins on the taggings. What's a more performant way to implement filter-by-multiple tag queries?

Is there a good NoSQL approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a NoSQL or document-oriented scenario, you'd have the actual tags as part of your document, likely stored as a list.  Since you've tagged this question with "couchdb", I'll use that as an example.

A "post" document in CouchDB might look like:

```
{
   "_id": <generated>,
   "question": "Question?",
   "answers": [... list of answers ...],
   "tags": ["mysql", "tagging", "joins", "nosql", "couchdb"]
}
```

Then, to generate a view keyed by tags:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/tags",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
      "all": {
         "map": "function(doc) {
            emit(doc.tags, null);
         }"
      }
   }
}
```

In CouchDB, you can issue an HTTP POST with multiple keys, if you wish.  An example is in [the documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Access.2BAC8-Query).  Using that technique, you would be able to search by multiple tags.

Note: Setting the value to null, above, helps keep the views small.  Use `include_docs=true` in your query if you want to see the actual documents as well.